# How to diagnose an application crash involving LuaJIT

Tags: c, lua, luajit

I'm trying to load a chunk of Lua from some text not stored on the file system. I added an element to `package.loaders` to do this from C.  As soon as I call `lua_load`, in C, to load/execute the chunk, the application aborts, crashes, no exception was raised.  The app is gone.

This is a pretty big problem.  Right now I'm trying to debug this one problem, but what happens if this happens in production for real?  I must be missing something.  How do we write quality, production code without LuaJIT aborting the app?  I'm missing something.  What am I missing?

[A related SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953096/c-and-lua5-1-2-luajit) suggested running the app with regular Lua.  I did it and it worked fine.  So something in LuaJIT doesn't like my code.  I can't find it.

I may be asking two questions:

- How to find the specific problem with this particular code right now.  Works in regular Lua, fails in LuaJIT.
- How do we use LuaJIT so that when it hits something it doesn't like, that it won't completely abort the entire process?

The crash in LuaJIT is in lib_package.c at `lua_call(L, 1, 1);  /* run loaded module */` which is around `line 431`.

Comment: Did you run it in plain Lua _with API checking enabled?_ Lua will let you misuse the C API in ways that LuaJIT doesn't, but should pick the issues up if you enable API checking.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.  I had an extra call to lua_pop() in my code.

Comment: How do we tell LuaJIT not to totally abort the entire app when it finds something it doesn't like?  Or is this not a problem once you get the C API set and compiled?

Comment: Aborting (or crashing) the entire application is a reasonable response to a programmer error, so that the developer is forced to find and fix the bug. And apparently it works well! LuaJIT has API checking as well, btw. Look for `LUA_USE_APICHECK` in the LuaJIT Makefile ...

Comment: No it isn't.  An exception is a reasonable response.  An exception is like saying, "Hey, here's a problem, can you handle it now? If not, unhandled exception and app crash" vs "App Crash <silence>" and then the programmer has to spend hours scratching head.

Comment: C doesn't have exceptions. Even in C++, underflows are still considered undefined behavior and will likely either trigger a segfault or break your program in other ways. API checking is disabled by default, because it's slow, and well-formed programs and libraries don't need it.